# Angularjs select filter on a translation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a problem and I don't see how to deal with it simply.

I have a select with option (with ng-repeat in it, I don't use ng-options to do that because I need to have ng-class on option).

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text">

<select class="span12 long-list" multiple="multiple">
    <option  ng-class="whatever" value="{{ element[idAttribute] }}"
             ng-repeat="element in elements | filter:query">
                 {{ element[valueAttribute] | translate }}
    </option>
</select>
```

This code is part of a template directive so valueAttribute and idAttribute are dynamique.

With this code, the filter is applied on my elements objects. 
The problem is that the filter only applies on untranslated content of the object and I want it to be applied on the object AND the translated value.

Is there a simple way to do it in using only the view ?

I see two solutions to do it but I have to manipulate other part of the code :
- Use a custom filter wich translate the value before filtering it
- Add in each element object a translated attribute

thank you

Comment: There is no simple way to do it. Filters only change the display of the data, they don't modify the data, so you need to process your data with the attached translations.